# Observables return type

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm sending my request to the API and parsing it with the map function:

```js
//part of service
post(url: string, params): Observable<Response> {
    let requestUrl: string = this.apiUrl + url;
    return this.http.post(requestUrl, params)
        .map(response => response.json());
}
    
//part of other service
doLogin(login, haslo): Observable<Response> {
    return this.apiService.post('auth/login/', {login: login, haslo: haslo});
}
```

As a result I get a boolean value and use it in subscribe function:

```js
this.authService.doLogin(this.model.login, this.model.haslo)
    .subscribe(result => {
        //result is boolean - not Response
        this.authService.loggedIn = result;
        this.result = result
    });
```

The problem is that in `doLogin`'s subscriber, TypeScript says that result is `Response` instead of `boolean` - how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's cause of your function prototypes:

post(url: string, params): Observable<**Response**>

doLogin(login, haslo): Observable<**Response**>

They should be:

Observable<**boolean**>

Do it like this:

```js
//part of service
post(url: string, params): Observable<any> {
    let requestUrl: string = this.apiUrl + url;
    return this.http.post(requestUrl, params)
        .map(response => response.json());
}

//part of other service
doLogin(login, haslo): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.apiService.post('auth/login/', {login: login, haslo: haslo})
       .map(result => result == true /* or any check here and return an BOOLEAN !!*/);
}
```

Comment: But it's not always true. `Post` method turns result to json (it can be any data) so it should be Observable<Object> and `doLogin` could by Observable<boolean> but typescript disagrees - it has to be Object. At the end `result` is Object not boolean :/